# ManyToManyField present in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 03 models book->target_readers and book has collection.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.title, self.reference)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)

class Collection(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
                                       )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    target_readers = models.ManyToManyField(Target_Readers, blank=True, null=True)

class Target_Readers(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="target reader")
```

In my template i do like this to get the target_readers of the book

```
{% for book in books %}
   {{ book.title }}
   {{ book.public_price }}
   {{ book.collection.target_readers.name }}
```

But I don't get the any results for target reader.

Anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a clearly worded, answerable question. +1 from me.

Comment: PS - for the record, django templates basically ignore 'incorrect' tags or ones with unprintable values, so rather than throwing an error on {{ book.collection.target_readers.name }} it just skipped it. I believe you can tell it to throw an error by setting TEMPLATE_DEBUG in your settings.py file. more info: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for book in books %}
   {{ book.title }}
   {{ book.public_price }}
   {% for reader in book.collection.target_readers %}
       {{ reader.name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`target_readers` is not a single entity, it's a list (albeit one which *may* just contain a single element).

Comment: I think it should be: for reader in book.collection.target_readers.all

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {{ book.title }}
    {{ book.public_price }}
    {{ book.collection.target_readers.all|join:", " }}
{% endfor %}
```

So `book.collection.target_readers.all` returns list of target readers' names and `join:", "` is a filter that concatenates list items with ", ".

Note: In this example `book.collection.target_readers.all` returns list of names, because you return `self.name` in your `__unicode__(self)` function of Target_Readers class.